# Accessing variable in different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*What is the proper way to access my variable `uid` from App.js in another file?*

I have a variable `uid` which is given a users unique UID after they log in via Google auth (Firebase).

I define the variable outside (above) my constructer:

```
var uid;

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.addPlayer = this.addPlayer.bind(this);
this.downvotePlayer = this.downvotePlayer.bind(this);
this.upvotePlayer = this.upvotePlayer.bind(this);
this.database = firebase.database().ref().child('players');
this.userLogIn = this.userLogIn.bind(this);
this.userLogOut = this.userLogOut.bind(this);

this.state = {
  players: [],
  user: null,
  weekTabVisible: null,
  byeTabVisible: null
}
this.players = [];
}
```

Later, when the user logs in and Auth() is called, `uid` is given a value.

```
componentDidMount() {
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.setState({ user });
    uid = user.uid;
  }
});
}
```

At this point, I use `uid` multiple times in this App.js file.

What is the proper way to access this `uid` value in another file? When I tried to set uid up as a prop, I was having trouble getting anything but undefined in my other page when I used `this.props.uid`

The component file I'm trying to use it on is Player.jsx, and I was adding it into my render() in App.js like so (and above in the constructor)

```
<Player
  playerContent={player.playerContent}
  playerId={player.id}
  key={player.id}
  upvotePlayer={this.upvotePlayer}
  downvotePlayer={this.downvotePlayer}
  userLogIn={this.userLogIn}
  userLogOut={this.userLogOut}
  uid={this.uid}
/>
```

I'm fairly new to ReactJS so I tried some docs and tutorials but I'm seeming to get confused on how the variable would be passed through elsewhere as a prop.

Thanks in advance

---

### Edit

Solved this going off what @Spencer Wieczorek suggested. I added `this.uid = null` to my App constructor and used this.uid to reference. Then after passing uid = {this.uid} in the Player component in App.js, I was able to reference uid by using `this.props.uid` in Player.jsx

Comment: `uid` should be apart of `<App>`. Which you then define as attributes to your child `<App ... > .. <Player uid={this.uid} /> ..</App>`. If you already have this structure it's because `this.uid` isn't defined as you didn't make it apart of the class `App`.

Comment: You could make uid part of another object, say var globalParams  = {uid: uid}; then pass globalParams as a parameter and the underlying uid will reference the same place in memory. If you pass by value, changing one place won't change elsewhere.